# check if the page is on the top of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if an html page is on the top of the window or not.

So, i am using this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   a = ($(window).scrollTop());
   if (a>0) {
      alert('page not in top');
   }
});
```

But this is not working as expected because the event should be fired only when the user stops the scroll action. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var timer = null;
$(window).addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if(timer !== null) {
        clearTimeout(timer);        
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
          // do something
    }, 150);
}, false);
```

Or this one:

```
    var timer;
    $(window).bind('scroll',function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout( refresh , 150 );
    });
    var refresh = function () { 
        // do stuff
        console.log('Stopped Scrolling'); 
    };
```

Comment: Thanks. "addEventListener is not a function" in the first code. Anyway, the second works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout`:

```
var timeout;

$(window).scroll(function() {
   clearTimeout(timeout);
   timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      a = $(window).scrollTop();
      if ( a > 0 ) {
           alert('page not in top');
      }
   }, 100);
});
```